# C++ Operator Overloading in expression

Tags: c++, expression, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm sure this has already been answered somewhere, but I don't know what to search for.

I have the following situation. I made a Vector class and overloaded the "*" (multiply by escalar) and the "+" operators (add two vectors). Now, the following line of code:

```
Vector sum = (e_x*u_c) + (e_y*u_r);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' in '((Teste*)this)->Teste::e_x.Vector::operator*(u_c) + ((Teste*)this)->Teste::e_y.Vector::operator*(u_r)'
```

But, if I replace this error line by:

```
Vector aux = (e_x*u_c);
Vector aux2 = (e_y*u_r);
Vector sum = aux + aux2;
```

I get no errors at all. Why? Aren't those two expressions meant to be equivalent?

EDIT:
Here are my the definitions of "*" and "+":]

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector& right)
{
    return Vector(x + right.x, y + right.y, z + right.z);
}
double Vector::operator*(Vector& right)
{
    return this->scalar_product(right);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of the operator overloads?

Comment: Yes. I will add it to the question

Comment: e_x and e_y are of type Vector, right  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace `Vector& right` with `const Vector& right`.

The expression `(e_x*u_c)` is an rvalue, and references to non-const won't bind to rvalues.

Also, the member functions themselves should be marked `const` as well:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& right) const
{
    return Vector(x + right.x, y + right.y, z + right.z);
}

double Vector::operator*(const Vector& right) const
{
    return this->scalar_product(right);
}
```

`scalar_product` will also have to be marked `const`. Read more about const correctness [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Comment: Ah right!! that makes 100% sense now!! It can't apply the operator to an rvalue since I could change it (without the const keyword)  Thanks for the fix AND explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

The declarations aren't right.

```
T T::operator +(const T& b) const;​

T T::operator *(const T& b) const;
```

[**Operators in C and C++**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)